# Spring lombok @AllArgsConstructor is not working

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-data, spring-tool-suite

I am using lombok but looks like @AllArgConstructor is not working when i'm create object of that class Sts is showing as

Description Resource    Path    Location    Type
The constructor Employee(String, String, String[]) is undefined EmployeeController.java /spring-solr/src/main/java/com/ajay/solr/controller line 21 Java Problem

```
package com.ajay.solr.model;

import org.apache.solr.client.solrj.beans.Field;
import org.springframework.data.annotation.Id;
import org.springframework.data.solr.core.mapping.SolrDocument;

import lombok.AllArgsConstructor;
import lombok.Data;
import lombok.NoArgsConstructor;

@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@SolrDocument(collection = "Employee")
public class Employee {

    @Id
    @Field
    private int id;
    @Field
    private String name;
    @Field
    private String[] address;

}
```

And the class where I am using is

```
package com.ajay.solr.controller;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

import com.ajay.solr.model.Employee;
import com.ajay.solr.repository.EmployeeRepository;

@RestController
    public class EmployeeController {
@Autowired
    private EmployeeRepository empRepository;

    public void addEmployees() {
        List<Employee> employees =  new ArrayList<>();
        employees.add(new Employee(373,"Sunil",new String[] {"Hyderabad","Gazipur"}));
        employees.add(new Employee(374,"Ajay",new String[] {"AnjaiyahNagar","Maharajganj"}));
        employees.add(new Employee(375,"Praveen",new String[] {"SRNagar","Baliya"}));
    }
}
```

Comment: id is an int. You're passing a String.

Comment: Now that you edited your code, there is no way for that code to generate the error that you have posted.

Comment: Add one more annotation @RequiredArgsConstructor

Comment: @BipilRaut Why should that fix the issue? There's no `@NonNull` field.

Comment: @JB Nizet: I referred from here  https://github.com/Java-Techie-jt/spring-data-solr

Answer (score 3):

If you are using STS. You must have Lombok installed in your Eclipse by running lombok-xyz.jar

Please Try the Following the Steps:

1.Include pom in Maven .
   2. Exit/Shutdown STS
   3. Find lombok Jar from https://projectlombok.org/download

```
4.From Command Prompt/Shell java -jar lombok-1.x.y.jar
```

This will open a pop-up screen, then specify your path for STS/Eclipse.exe

5. Hit the install button
6. Start STS/Eclipse

(If you are still facing the issue, try updating your project: right-click on project -> Maven -> Update Project and the errors will disappear.)

Answer (score 0):

```
annotationProcessor 'org.projectlombok:lombok'
compileOnly 'org.projectlombok:lombok'
```

Adding this in my build.gradle file, worked.

Answer (score 0):

Try installing lombok plugins or extensions, I had the same problem and I solved it like this

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).